# Agrupar por hora los registros de las últimas 24 horas

Tags: mysql

Cuando genero el siguiente filtro me da la lista de registros correctamente por registro *(12pm del dia anterior a 9am del dia actual)*:

```
SELECT hour(from_unixtime(time_stamp)) as hora 
FROM access_log
WHERE from_unixtime(time_stamp) >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

*Listado con el filtro anterior:*

[image: Listado con el filtro anterior]

Pero cuando deseo agrupar para que de este orden:

```
12
13
14
...
23
0
1
2
...
8
9
```

Usando esta consulta:

```
SELECT hour(from_unixtime(time_stamp)) as hora
FROM access_log
WHERE from_unixtime(time_stamp) >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY hora
```

Da este formato:

[image: ¿¿??]

¿Alguna sugerencia para agrupar por hora los registros de las últimas 24 horas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sólo necesitas ordenar por tu campo de fecha, sino por defecto ordena por orden asc del campo que está seleccionando ya formateado.

```
SELECT hour(from_unixtime(time_stamp)) as hora FROM access_log WHERE from_unixtime(time_stamp) >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY GROUP BY hora
ORDER BY from_unixtime(time_stamp) ASC
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Esta opción salió genial. Me dió los resultados como deseaba. Por lo que observo, obvié el uso del ORDER BY dejando el trabajo a GROUP BY. ¡Muchas gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Exactamente. No hay de que :)

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de entender bien tu pregunta, pero, si usas el ORDER BY, en teoría obtendrías el resultado que deseas.

Prueba modificando tu consulta así:

```
SELECT hour(from_unixtime(time_stamp)) as hora
FROM access_log
WHERE from_unixtime(time_stamp) >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY hora
ORDER BY hora
```

Answer (score 0):

Primer punto, la única sentencia que te garantiza un orden es el `ORDER BY`, cualquier otra puede que te retorne un orden, pero no hay garantías que es orden sea siempre el mismo. Segundo, necesitas un orden distinto al natural numérico, quieres comenzar desde las 12 ir hasta las 23 y luego de 0 a 11. Puedes implementar este orden particular de las siguiente forma:

```
SELECT  hour(from_unixtime(time_stamp)) as hora
    FROM access_log
    WHERE from_unixtime(time_stamp) >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    GROUP BY hora
    ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN hour(from_unixtime(time_stamp)) >= 12 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, 
        hour(from_unixtime(time_stamp))
```

En este caso usamos `CASE WHEN hour(from_unixtime(time_stamp)) >= 12 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END` para ordenar primero las horas desde las 12 en adelante y luego las que van de 0 a 11.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, funcionó de la manera que esperaba!